# Are alkynes weakly polar?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, polarity

I was reading about physical properties of alkynes in my [Chemistry textbook](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kech206.pdf).

One of the sentence states

> Alkynes are weakly polar in nature.

I didn't understand how alkynes are weakly polar, so I tried to search about it on the internet but couldn't find any explanation.

Many sites (like [this](https://www.angelo.edu/faculty/kboudrea/molecule_gallery/03_alkynes/00_alkynes.htm) and [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Alkynes/Properties_of_Alkynes)) rather state that alkynes are non-polar.

My question is: are alkynes weakly polar? If yes, why?

Comment: All chemical compounds are weakly polar anyway.

Comment: Your textbook should've defined such descriptive term. Or, better, avoid using nonquantitative terms for teaching crucial concepts [incorrectly].

Comment: @MissMulan Would an isolated homo-diatomic molecule like $\ce{H2}$ or $\ce{O2}$ also be weakly polar?

Comment: Yes due to London dispersion.The least polar molecule is F-F.

Comment: Are we talking about "polar" or "polarizable" here?

Comment: @IanBush even X-X bonds are polar because valence bond electrons always have the probability of being closer to one of the X.However  the higher the electronegativity of the X atom is , the less possible this is.This is why N2,02,CL2 can become liquids or even solids at very low temperatures.

Comment: That is not the usual definition of "polar" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_polarity https://www.britannica.com/science/polarity-chemistry https://biologydictionary.net/polar-molecule/

Comment: "Polar" means having electric dipole moment by any means possible.

Comment: Any molecule that doesn't have the right symmetry is at least slightly polar, even saturated hydrocarbons. acetylene isn't polar but only because it is highly symmetric. Propylene, though,  is (slightly) polar.

Comment: Nonpolar = not more polar than weakly. Polar = not less polar than very  :-)

Comment: We have talked about polarity too often on this site already. Usually without real conclusions. It's so fuzzy and ill-defined that not even the IUPAC Gold Book has a definition for it. Alas, for most intents and purposes, if a molecule has no permanent dipole, it's called nonpolar. The rest you can consider polar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, alkynes can display a (small) permanent electric dipole moment, and thus are polar molecules by the usual definition. For example see https://cccbdb.nist.gov/exp2x.asp?casno=74997&charge=0 where the dipole moment for propyne is given as 0.780 Debye. Given such a molecule is asymmetric is it shouldn't be a surprise that there is a dipole moment.